# 500 Action does not contain method named

Tags: jsp, actions

Estou efetuando uma chamada de uma action mas recebo a exception de que o método não existe na Action:

```
500 Action[/historicoAction] does not contain method named listar
```

Alguém saberia dizer o que está acontecendo?

Segue arquivos:

## `struts-config`

```
<form-bean name="historicoForm" type="br.com.liquigas.portal.form.HistoricoForm"/>

<forward name="/historicoAction" path="/historicoAction.do"></forward>

<action path="/historicoAction" type="br.com.liquigas.portal.action.HistoricoAction" name="historicoForm" scope="request" parameter="method">
    <forward name="success" path="/jsp/historico/historicoPedido.jsp"></forward>
    <forward name="failure" path="/jsp/historico/erro.jsp"></forward>
    <forward name="historicoPedido" path="/jsp/historico/historicoPedido.jsp"></forward>
    <forward name="historicoProduto" path="/jsp/historico/historicoProduto.jsp"></forward>
</action>
```

## JSP

```
<a class="ovalbutton" href="#" onclick="return avancar();"><span>Avan&ccedil;ar</span></a>
```

## Javascript

```
function avancar(){
    $("#method").val("listar");
    $('#historicoForm').submit();
    alert("Avancou");
    return false;
}
```

## FORM

```
public class HistoricoForm extends GenericForm {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7434349782026204632L;

    /**
     * Filtro da tela com o numero do pedido
     */
    private String numeroPedido;

    /**
     * Filtro da tela com o codigo do cliente
     */
    private String codigoCliente;

    /**
     * Filtro da tela com a Dta Inicial da pesquisa
     */
    private String dataInicial;

    /**
     * Filtro da tela com a Dta Final da pesquisa
     */
    private String dataFinal;

    /**
     * Lista com as informações do historico
     */
    private List historicoList;

    /**
     * Lista com as informações do Histórico do produto, a tela de detalhe do historico
     */
    private List historicoProdutoList;

    /**
     * parametro da jsp
     */
    private String method;

    /**
     * @return o numeroPedido
     */
    public String getNumeroPedido() {
        return numeroPedido;
    }

    /**
     * @param numeroPedido o numeroPedido a ser configurado
     */
    public void setNumeroPedido(String numeroPedido) {
        this.numeroPedido = numeroPedido;
    }

    /**
     * @return o codigoCliente
     */
    public String getCodigoCliente() {
        return codigoCliente;
    }

    /**
     * @param codigoCliente o codigoCliente a ser configurado
     */
    public void setCodigoCliente(String codigoCliente) {
        this.codigoCliente = codigoCliente;
    }

    /**
     * @return o dataInicial
     */
    public String getDataInicial() {
        return dataInicial;
    }

    /**
     * @param dataInicial o dataInicial a ser configurado
     */
    public void setDataInicial(String dataInicial) {
        this.dataInicial = dataInicial;
    }

    /**
     * @return o dataFinal
     */
    public String getDataFinal() {
        return dataFinal;
    }

    /**
     * @param dataFinal o dataFinal a ser configurado
     */
    public void setDataFinal(String dataFinal) {
        this.dataFinal = dataFinal;
    }

    /**
     * @return o historicoList
     */
    public List getHistoricoList() {
        return historicoList;
    }

    /**
     * @param historicoList o historicoList a ser configurado
     */
    public void setHistoricoList(List historicoList) {
        this.historicoList = historicoList;
    }

    /**
     * @return o historicoProdutoList
     */
    public List getHistoricoProdutoList() {
        return historicoProdutoList;
    }

    /**
     * @param historicoProdutoList o historicoProdutoList a ser configurado
     */
    public void setHistoricoProdutoList(List historicoProdutoList) {
        this.historicoProdutoList = historicoProdutoList;
    }

    /**
     * @return o method
     */
    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    /**
     * @param method o method a ser configurado
     */
    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }
```

## ACTION

```
public ActionForward listar(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Galera, consegui resolver meu problema com uma simples alteração nos parâmetros do método ActionForward. O que apresentava problema era o método:

public ActionForward detalhe(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            **HttpActionRequest** request, ActionResponse response) throws Exception {
}

Tentei também com o:
public ActionForward detalhe(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            **HttpRequest** request, ActionResponse response) throws Exception {
}

e não funcionou....

**Corrigido** com o

public ActionForward detalhe(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            **ActionRequest** request, ActionResponse response) throws Exception {
}